# Cannot login to CentOS7

Tags: centos, users, login

I was trying to set the environment in .bashrc and I might change something incorrectly, now I cannot login as either common user or root.
I use centos gui in my PC, when I enter the password  the page just go back to the very first user choosing page. I am not sure where I can check anything.
[image]

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + F2` login, revert the changes, `Alt + F1` or `F7` -> login graphically.

Answer (score 0):

As Artem suggested, switch to a virtual terminal and log in using the cli. You can revert the `.bashrc` to the original state and try again. Second option is if you have `ssh` access from another system, log in that way and again revert `.bashrc`.

Last option and the most painful. Boot from a recovery image, mount the root and home partitions, and revert.